# What is the difference between S3 Multi-Region Access Points and AWS CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Can anyone explain the difference between **S3 Multi-Region Access Points** and **AWS CloudFront**?

The documentation for a multi-region access point states:

> Multi-Region Access Points offer a global S3 hostname that provides access to multiple S3 buckets across AWS Regions with automatic routing and failover between buckets.

The documentation for CloudFront states:

> Content delivery networks provide a globally-distributed network of proxy servers that cache content, such as web videos or other bulky media, more locally to consumers, thus improving access speed for downloading the content.

There are of course major differences between both descriptions, but generalized speaking I understand both services as solutions to deliver content faster and more efficiently. What are there main differences?

Answer (score 2):

**S3 Multi-Region Access Points:**
You can have multiple buckets (in multiple regions) and this service will automatically route the users to the nearest bucket. Thus enabling you to separate the buckets using the single bucket architecture. You can also use the private link and then connect to your s3 buckets using AWS private network. S3 Multi-Region Access Points also give you a new S3 Management Console experience for managing all aspects of a multi-region S3 setup. In the S3 Management Console, S3 Multi-Region Access Points show a centralized view of the underlying replication topology, replication metrics, and your request routing configuration. This gives you an even easier way to build, manage, and monitor storage for multi-region applications.

**AWS CloudFront** Amazon CloudFront is a web service that speeds up the distribution of your static and dynamic web content, such as .html, .css, .js, and image files, to your users. CloudFront delivers your content through a worldwide network of data centers called edge locations.

In case you are now wondering what is the difference between **AWS Transfer Accelerator** It accelerates transfer to a single bucket using AWS private network. Users upload data to the nearest edge location and then AWS copies the data from the edge location to the bucket's location using its own network.

Answer (score 0):

So cloudfront gives a single url for global access to Web content (cached locally - at cloudfront endpoints), and Multi-Region Access Points gives a single global access point for all S3 data (stored locally - in an S3 bucket for each region).